# Regular conjugacy classes and irreducible representations in the infinite, projective case

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, group-cohomology

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $G$ a (not necessarily finite) group. Let $\alpha\colon G\times G\to k^*$ be a multiplier, meaning that

- $\alpha(s,t)\alpha(st,r)=\alpha(s,tr)\alpha(t,r)$ for all $s,t,r\in G$;
- $\alpha(e,s)=\alpha(s,e)=1$ for all $s\in G$.

An element $a\in G$ is said to be *$\alpha$-regular* if $\alpha(x,a)=\alpha(a,x)$ for all $x$ in the centralizer of $a$ in $G$. Note that conjugation preserves $\alpha$-regularity, so we may speak of $\alpha$-regular conjugacy classes.

A *projective $\alpha$-representation* of $G$ is a map $\pi\colon G\to GL(n,k)$ satisfying
$$\pi(s)\pi(t)=\alpha(s,t)\pi(s,t)$$
for all $s,t\in G$. In the case of the trivial multiplier $\alpha\equiv 1$, we get ordinary linear representations.

I would like to know, for a given $\alpha$, how abundant $\alpha$-regular conjugacy classes are.

As I understand, when $G$ is finite, the number of irreducible linear representations of $G$ is equal to the number of conjugacy classes of $G$. Furthermore, the number of irreducible projective $\alpha$-representations of $G$ is equal to the number of $\alpha$-regular conjugacy classes of $G$.

With this in mind, let me start by asking:

**Question 1:** Is there a general relationship between the cardinality of irreducible representations of $G$ and the cardinality of conjugacy classes of $G$?

**Question 2:** Is there a general relationship between the cardinality of irreducible projective $\alpha$-representations of $G$ and the cardinality of $\alpha$-regular conjugacy classes of $G$?

The more specific question I'm interested in is:

**Question 3:** Is there a way to construct non-identity $\alpha$-regular conjugacy classes (either by using irreducible projective $\alpha$-representations or by other means)?

Comment: In both questions the "numbers which you would like to relate" could both be infinite (think of $G={\bf Z}$ for instance). To avoid trivial answers, maybe you could try to rephrase/rethink your questions to better reflect what you're trying to find?